# Copy a db from resources xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, file, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

In `Xamarin.Android` project for retrieving files (DBs) set as `AndroidResource` from the `Assets folder`, copy them in the `Personal folder`, I did something like this in the `MainActivity.cs`:

```cs
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            //...
            LoadApplication(new App());

            //Database
            ExtractDBFromAssets(dbname: "Italiano.db");
            ExtractDBFromAssets(dbname: "Inglese.db");
            ExtractDBFromAssets(dbname: "Francese.db");

        }

        public void ExtractDBFromAssets(string dbname)
        {
            string destination = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(destination, dbname);

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
            {
                using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    Assets.Open(dbname).CopyTo(writeStream);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, assuming I have also stored the same files inside `Resources folder` in `Xamarin.iOS` and set them as `BundleResource`, **how can I achieve the same result as in the Android file**?

I tried this in `AppDelegate.cs`, but it seems not to work:

```cs
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            //...
            LoadApplication(new App());

            //Database
            ExtractBDFromResources("Italiano", "db");
            ExtractBDFromResources("Inglese", "db");
            ExtractBDFromResources("Francese", "db");

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        public static void ExtractBDFromResources(string dbname, string type)
        {
            string destination = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(destination, dbname);

            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(dbname, type), filename);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: in iOS you can just include them in the project root as "content" files and read them with normal File I/O

Comment: @Jason Ok thanks, but what about the file path?

Comment: they are relative to the root of the project, so you can just use "filename.ext" without a path

Comment: Yes, that's fair

Comment: I tried your code with an image file and it works on my side. It should also work with a db file. Make sure the db name you use in the code is the same as the db name which placed in your project.